# web page takes long time to respond and after second attempt it return to normal

Tags: java, jsp, web, tomcat6

I have deployed my web application(jsp+servlet) on tomcat 6(6.0.26) on linux server.This problem happen when I want to access the web page at the first time and after second attempt, it will no problem, the page load successfully .My index files contain news module that query data from database.If there any suggestion to avoid this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DBs caches the query result or at least update its own optimizer. in your first query it takes time to retrieve but consecutive queries will be much faster. so check your query how much it takes time for first time queries in your db IDE and optimize your query.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of reasons

- The DB caches the query results after the first call
- Thats because Tomcat compiles the JSP file only at the 1st attempt they are accessed , after the 1st attempt the loading fast because the JSP file is already compiled into a Servlet class.[How to configure tomcat to precompile](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jasper-howto.html)